# ORA-16706: Data Guard broker worker process not available

Tags: oracle, dataguard

Database version is 12.1.0.1.
We have one primary database and two physical standby database and dataguard also configured.

Dataguard sync is fine working between primary and physical standby.(No lag)

While checking the status of standby database by using DGMGRL getting below error

> DGM-17016: failed to retrieve status for database "xxx_x" 
>   (xxxx_x - standbydbname)
>   ORA-16706: Data Guard broker worker process not available

Comment: How did you configure the standbys ? put dgmgrl commands here

Comment: DGMGRL> show database verbose 'ABC_D'

Database - ABC_D

  Role:              PHYSICAL STANDBY
  Intended State:    APPLY-ON
  Transport Lag:     0 seconds (computed 1 second ago)
  Apply Lag:         0 seconds (computed 1 second ago)
  Apply Rate:        499.00 KByte/s
  Real Time Query:   OFF
  Instance(s):
    ABC
     ..
  ..
  ..

Database Status:
DGM-17016: failed to retrieve status for database "ABC_D"
ORA-16713: the Data Guard broker command timed out

Comment: DGMGRL> show configuration;

Configuration - Dataguard_ABC

  Protection Mode: MaxPerformance
  Databases:
  ABC_P - Primary database
    ABC_F - Physical standby database
    ABC_D - Physical standby database
      Error: ORA-16810: multiple errors or warnings detected for the database

Fast-Start Failover: DISABLED

Configuration Status:
ERROR

Comment: Please find above, standby redo log creation done by alter database add standby command

Comment: Check if "ALTER SYSTEM SET dg_broker_start=TRUE SCOPE=BOTH;" on all environments, also check if no firewall betwen servers, read once again https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-1007327

Comment: Dg_broker_start is true in both servers. While disable the firewall also same error exist.

Comment: Please find below :

Comment: DGMGRL> show databaSE 'ABC_P'

Database - ABC_P

  Role:              PRIMARY
  Intended State:    TRANSPORT-ON
  Instance(s):
    ABC

Database Status:
SUCCESS

Comment: DGMGRL> show database 'ABC_D'

Database - ABC_D

  Role:              PHYSICAL STANDBY
  Intended State:    APPLY-ON
  Transport Lag:     0 seconds (computed 0 seconds ago)
  Apply Lag:         0 seconds (computed 0 seconds ago)
  Apply Rate:        405.00 KByte/s
  Real Time Query:   OFF
  Instance(s):
    ABC

Database Status:
DGM-17016: failed to retrieve status for database "ABC_D"
ORA-16713: the Data Guard broker command timed out

Comment: DGMGRL> show database 'ABC_F'

Database - ABC_F

  Role:              PHYSICAL STANDBY
  Intended State:    APPLY-ON
  Transport Lag:     0 seconds (computed 0 seconds ago)
  Apply Lag:         0 seconds (computed 0 seconds ago)
  Apply Rate:        535.00 KByte/s
  Real Time Query:   ON
  Instance(s):
    ABC

Database Status:
SUCCESS

Comment: while checking the status, abc_d is real time apply off and for another standby abc_f is on.

Comment: for both, the lag is 0 seconds. why the real-time query is off in abc_d. please give a solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments for my doubts.

As now I have found a root cause and fix. 
Please find a fix:

The Broker is killing the RSM0 process and restarting it because of an internal timeout that is too low. This can happen even in network choke condition also. 
Please provide what the OperationTimeout is set to.
DGMGRL> connect sys/
DGMGRL> show configuration OperationTimeout;

SOLUTION
Increase the OperationTimeout or apply the patch.
If this shows low 30-120, then set it higher, up to 600 (10 mins) :

DGMGRL> EDIT CONFIGURATION SET PROPERTY OperationTimeout=600;

Configuration - Dataguard_ABC

Protection Mode: MaxPerformance
  Databases:
  ABC_P - Primary database
    ABC_F - Physical standby database 
    ABC_D - Physical standby database

Then works fine.